# How do use find when expecting multiple values?

Tags: mongodb

I have a collection such as this:

```
{ emails: [ 
    { address: 'ex@example.com', valid: true }, 
    { address: 'test@example.com', valid: false }
          ]
}
```

How would I make a find() query so that I get all documents with a specific 'address'? (I don't care about the 'valid' value or any other fields, as long as emails[*].address is the same.

Answer (score 3):

Use dot notation in your query object:

```js
db.coll.find({'emails.address': 'ex@example.com'})
```